# How to link to different version of a shared object (.so) on different version of Ubuntu?

Tags: c++, symbolic-link, versions, shared-library

I have developed a program which links to `ncurses-dev` and I made a .deb installer for it.

On Ubuntu 18, my main binary links to `libncurses.so.5`, but on Ubuntu 20, `libncurses.so.6` exists instead of `libncurses.so.5`, so my installed binary can not load libncurses.so.5.

If my program is re-compiled on Ubuntu 20, it works because it links to libncurses.so.6 by the re-compiling.

What's the common techniques to solve this kind of problem?

Comment: You snapshot the dependency versions so they match one release of Ubuntu. You compile for that release. You put the appropriate versions of dependencies in the deb control file. Rinse and repeat for the next release of Ubuntu. A .deb is NOT an installer -- apt/dpkg is the installer.

Comment: FYI:  With the Ubuntu Core 18 & 20 releases; the requirements get bound & work for releases; a benefit of the *snap* package; as they'll just require Core18 but work on 16, 18, 20 & 22 without change.  The *year* format products (18, 20) differ to the *year.month* products, ie. 18 & 18.04, or 20 & 20.04 are different systems. If you package in *snap* for 18, 20, or 22 it'll work in all & even 16.